# Display a specific character followed by a digit from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var string = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";
```

I want to get the `"str1234"` only from the `string` variable. How do I do this?

Note that the index of substring `"str1234"` is not always consistent.

Comment: can you please post complete code,where this string sets?

Comment: Use substring to get the string

Comment: @mbadeveloper is saying that "index of substring "str1234" is not always consistent"

Comment: Does the string follow a regular pattern (ie. can you use a regular expression)? By index of substring, do you mean that the end is not always consistent, or the start is not always consistent? (ie. are said strings always in the format "Administration for administering x as an administrator")

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to search for patterns in strings.

To search for the pattern `str` followed by 1-4 numbers you would use the following expression:

`\bstr\d{1,4}\b`

**Explanation of RegExp by `regex101.com`**

> `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
>   `str` matches the characters `str` literally (case sensitive) .
>   `\d{1,4}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`) .
>   `{1,4}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) .
>   `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`

**In JavaScript:**

```
let input = 'Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator';
let match = input.match(/\bstr\d{1,4}\b/);
```

The object `match` can be used like this:

```
match[0]    // "str1234"
match.index // 33
match.input // "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator"
```

Comment: Thanks @dislick. This is almost somehow what I'm looking for. I tested your suggestion and found out that it only matches a word with an 'str' at the beginning using \b. So if I have a case like this:
var input = 'Administration for administering costr1234 as an administrator';
Thus, it returned null. 
Sometimes the word with 'str' from the string does not always begins with 'str' like the one above (costr1234).

Comment: Also, I also have cases like this. 
var input2 =  'Administration for administering costr1234 and comSTR5242 as an administrator in _STr4324';

I want to get all 'str1234', 'STR5242' and 'STr4324' and store it in an array. I will greatly appreciate your help in doing this!

Comment: Okay @Roger, try this: https://regex101.com/r/d9Wy3U/1. On the left side there is a "Code Generator" that you can use to see how you would use group matches in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use indexof()

```js
var string = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";

var index; index= string.indexOf('str1234')
console.log(index)
```

To change 'str1234' to someother value ,you can use replace() .

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OP needs to get that string followed by number which is not known.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as follows:

```js
var string = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";

var x = string.match(/str[\d]+/)
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";
var array = string.split(" ");
cont neededString;
for (const s of array) {
  if(s.startsWith('str')){
 neededString = s;
 break;
 }
//or
if(isAlphaNumeric(s))
{
neededString = s;
 break;
}
}

public boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s){
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
    return s.matches(pattern);
}
```

Comment: Snippet throwing error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can use *substr* function

```js
var text = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";
var textSearch = "str1234";
console.log(text.substr(text.indexOf(textSearch),textSearch.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `indexOf()` function by the following snippet:

```js
var string = "Administration for administering str1234 as an administrator";
var subString = "str1234";
if (string.indexOf(subString) >= 0) {
  alert(true); //You can add your functionality here.
}
```